# Fetch data from Drupal 8 by Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, frontend, fetch, drupal-8

Anyone of you know how to fetch data from Drupal 8 database. I want use Drupal 8 as backend because I barely know anything about backend, so Drupal 8 will be my first choice. I want use reactjs to fetch data. So anyone know how to do it? Any modules or plugin to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module may help : https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi

Installing and enabling this module, let's you serve drupal content as JSON/REST. Those API's can then be adapted by reactjs.

This tutorial might help too 
https://colorfield.be/blog/react-and-drupal-8-json-api-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to design api and then call it from react. It's a long story.

Comment: Any links to refer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal views (which is a core module). Views can be configured to output data as JSON through an endpoint.
Views are highly customisable so you'd be able to pass anything you want from your db.
Here is a little tutorial I found (not by me).

https://internetdevels.com/blog/views-rest-export-drupal-8